# Back in stock alert email isn't translated (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, email, localisation, stock, email-translation

In a new Magento 2 setup I'm testing the back in stock alert email, but the text in the email isn't translated. I'm using the dutch translation package of magento2translations, this contains the text from the email, but the email is still in English.

In magento/module-product-alert/view/frontend/templates/email/stock.phtml is the text located. It is using the default translation functionality of Magento:

```
<?= __('In stock alert! We wanted you to know that these products are now available:') ?>
```

The email looks like this:
[image: Back in stock alert email isn't translated (Magento 2)]

Does anyone have this problem too? Or does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Yes, same issue here. Did you already find a solution to this problem?

Comment: According to the Magento team, this problem is fixed in Magento 2.2 which released today. So updating should fix the problem! (https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8413)